# Constructor parameter becomes null inside class even though it is not in main in Java

Tags: java, class, constructor

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but i'm pretty new to Java.

This is my main.java, I checked with a debugger and chosenFile is not null

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import java.io.File;

//TIP To <b>Run</b> code, press <shortcut actionId="Run"/> or
// click the <icon src="AllIcons.Actions.Execute"/> icon in the gutter.
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "CSV Files", "csv");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            File chosenFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            // System.out.println(chosenFile.getAbsolutePath());
            if (chosenFile == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Null file in main");
            }
            questionAnswersInput inputFile = new questionAnswersInput(chosenFile); // Using a debugger I see that chosenFile is not null.
            System.out.println(inputFile);
        }
    }
}
```

In this questionAnswersInput.java class however inputFile becomes null and the exception is thrown only in the getPath() method.

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class questionAnswersInput {
    final private File inputFile;

    public questionAnswersInput(File inputFile) {
        if (inputFile == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null file in constructor"); // Nothing happens here even tho inputFile is already null
        }
        System.out.println(inputFile.getAbsolutePath()); // This line doesnt execute
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }

    private String getPath() {
        System.out.println(inputFile);
        if (this.inputFile == null) {
            System.out.println("Ciao");
            throw new NullPointerException("Null file when getting path"); // This is the exception
        }
        return this.inputFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    private String path = getPath();


}
```

I've been trying to wrap my head around it for a while but I don't understand what the issue could be. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend you 1) Add the exception stacktrace to the question 2) Fix the code formatting, so it is visible where the code block starts and where it ends. You may consider using https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-contents.html as a guide. Properly organised code is easy to read and find what is wrong with it.

Comment: Your IDE will format your code so that the indentation is correct. Please edit your question with correctly indented code.

Comment: @tgdavies I copied and pasted from IntelliJ.

Comment: @AndrejIstomin how do I do number 1?

Comment: Please format your code before copying it from IntelliJ. Use the Code, Reformat File... menu option.

Comment: @tgdavies donee

Comment: also, don't throw Exceptions except when needed. throwing that exception in your main method makes no sense at all, and can easily be exchanged for a conditional statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java has an awful quirk which really frustrates people learning the language. When you create a class, the order of initialization is as follows:

1. First, the constructor is invoked.
2. The first instruction in the constructor is an explicit or implicit invocation to the super's constructor, so that one gets invoked.
3. As soon as the super's constructor returns, every single field (member variable) of the current class gets initialized.
4. Finally, the rest of the constructor gets to run.

In your class you have an entirely superfluous `private String path = getPath();` this forces `getPath()` to be invoked before your constructor has had a chance to execute `this.inputFile = inputFile;`, thus, `inputFile` is `null` in `getPath()`.

To solve this problem, you can do one of the following:

- Get rid of the field initializer for `path`, (declare it uninitialized,) and then explicitly initialize it from within your constructor, ***after*** you have realized `inputFile`.
- Get rid of `path` altogether, and replace it with invocations of `getPath()`.